# What is the fastest way to transfer files to multiple clients at different times on the same network?

Tags: local-area-network, file-sharing

Im looking for the fastest method for transferring files to multiple client computers on the same network.  Here is some background of the situation for clarification

We have multiple client machines that we need to transfer files as quickly as possible, sometimes its a single large file, sometimes its thousands of small files.  The files are unchanging, but not all the clients need all the files.

As it is right now we have a server set up as a torrent tracker and 7 other systems working as seed boxes.  Clients will go to an intranet site that has links to the .torrent files that the clients need.  This method works, and we get decent speeds, however it requires that each client has a bit torrent client installed and that each user knows how to use it.

Im looking for some method to transfer files that doesn't require a special software to get the data, and only 1 location that they have to go to get it.  Is there anything that can be served up via HTTP or FTP variant, something through a browser?  There are 20-25 different downloads, that any one, or multiple will need to be downloaded by up to 100 or more clients.  downloads are between 7GB-35GB.

As this is for a 24 hour event, each download needs to be kept to less than an hour.  We have a 1Gb to the client and 10Gb backbone.  Oh and this is a predominantly windows environment, windows options are preferred, but if no options are available for windows, some basic linux isn't out of the realm of possibility.  We can get more hardware if needed as well.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well your network is going to be the biggest bottleneck. Beyond that the hard drives. A Windows server with a nice SSD RAID array fed through at least a 10Gb connection to a switch that feeds 1Gb connections to clients seems like the fastest you’re going to get. That 1Gb connection to the end points is the limit for any individual, unless your providing that hardware also with faster links. If there is any way to work in multicast that would be better, but doesn’t sound like it.

Comment: A bit more background.  This is for a LAN party.  Our venue has very limited Internet (50Mb) so we make steam backups of all of our games and host them locally for all the attendees to grab instead of downloading over the internet. Our server is running a stripped set of ssds, our seed boxes are running ssds as well.  Using the torrent method we can have 25 people pulling 80+MBPS on files.   However it requires a client.  How do data centers dish out files for websites? Obviously YouTube doesn't have 1 copy of a video and are relying on a single HDD for all requests

Comment: Static content is often over a content delivery network. There is a copy close to you with significant bandwidth.  The Google Global Cache has hundreds of nodes world wide, and peers with ISPs.

Answer (score 0):

100 clients downloading 35 GB, in an hour, will saturate a 10 Gb link. You need more bandwidth. Install multiple 10 Gb interfaces in the web server, or add more web servers. 25 Gb or faster Ethernet would be nice, if your storage can go that fast, and if you can upgrade your switches.

BitTorrent is ideal on a fast LAN. Be sure to add a web seed to the torrent, max out that web server interface to get it seeding.

Edit:

Or you can load balance web/ftp servers. DNS round robin is simple. Beware that  your switches need to exceed 10 Gb throughput to do any better, look at their packets per second specs. Take the desired number of concurrent users and multiply by that 80 MB/s you want, you need this much from the servers through the switches. Again, consider upgrade the core, to multiple 10 Gb or 25 Gb Ethernet.

Comment: I think there is still a bit of confusion on what im after.  Im all for saturating our 10Gb connection.  That im not concerned with.  Speed, isn't so much my issues as the torrent method is plenty fast.  What i want is an alternative method that is as fast or nearly so, that is 100% web based for the end user.  No clients required.  I have plenty of servers and gobs of SSDs.

maybe something setup to use network load balancing with DFS or something simular.  I just dont know though.  How do large coorperations server up files to hundereds of thousands without a client and torrent?

Comment: I edited in a load balancer option. Very likely you don't have enough bandwidth in your backbone links to max out 100 or even 25 clients in a client/server setup.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you sir, this answers my question. I doff my hat to you sir